# Jquery - infinitescroll loading spinner with imagesLoaded plugin

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll, jquery-masonry, imagesloaded

I'm using (masonry + imagesLoaded + infinitescroll) following [this](https://gist.github.com/gregrickaby/10383879) example, everything works fine except the loading spinner, it is hidden before imagesLoaded completed, here is my code:

```
var $container = $('#masonry-grid');

// Masonry + ImagesLoaded
$container.imagesLoaded().progress(function(){
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
    });
});

// Infinite Scroll
$container.infinitescroll({

        // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)
        navSelector  : ".navigation",
        // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
        nextSelector : ".nav-next a",
        // selector for all items you'll retrieve
        itemSelector : ".grid-item",

        // finished message
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: '<span class="no-more-events"> No more events to load, <strong>Stay Tuned!</strong>  </span>',
            img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif',
            msgText: "<em>Loading the next set of posts...</em>"
        },
        errorCallback: function() { $('#infscr-loading').animate({opacity: 0.8}, 15000).fadeOut('slow'); }
    },

    // Trigger Masonry as a callback
    function( newElements ) {
        // hide new items while they are loading
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).hide();

        // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
            // show elems now they're ready
            $newElems.show();
            $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
        });

});
```

the problem is that the loading spinner shows after the content is fetched but before the imagesLoaded() is done, I hide the newly loaded content until all images are loaded, as it shown in the last callback function `function( newElements )`

**How to show the loading spinner until imagesLoaded() function is done?**

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by hiding `#infscr-loading` div and added a new div `#loading-spin` to show the loading spinner, show it while masonry is loading and hide it after `imagesLoaded()` is completed.

```
// Trigger Masonry as a callback
        function( newElements ) {
            // hide new items while they are loading
            var $newElems = $( newElements ).hide();
            $('#loading-spin').show();
            // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $('#loading-spin').hide();
                // show elems now they're ready
                $newElems.show();
                RotateCardReset();  // Reset Rotating Cards
                $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
            });
        });
```